# Download to file and readystate = 4

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a code to download a very large file that, depending on bandwidth, may take 30 minutes to download.  I have a very basic script now, that typically terminates before the file is completely downloaded.  Is there a way to use readystate, or something similar, to make VBA allow the entire file to download before moving on?

Here's the code:

```
Sub Download()
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> URL of the Path
    strURL = "http://www.aeronav.faa.gov/upload_313-/terminal/DDTPPE_201612.zip"
    '~~> Destination for the file
    strPath = "c:\Users\username\Desktop\WebTest\database.zip"

    Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0)

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you should show the code that actually downloads the file.....

Comment: ... it does, doesn't it?  The file begins downloading when this line is executed:  Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strPath, 0, 0).

Comment: So I'm curious - why the -1 vote?  Is there something wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your URL in a cell and run the script below.

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub DownloadFilefromWeb()
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim URL As String, ext As String
    Dim buf, ret As Long
    URL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
    buf = Split(URL, ".")
    ext = buf(UBound(buf))
    strSavePath = "C:\Users\your_path_here\" & "DownloadedFile." & ext
    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
    If ret = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Download has been succeed!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

That's if you want to loop through a range with many URLs.  If you want to download just one, try it this way.

```
Declare Function URLDownloadToFileA Lib "urlmon" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub ExampleDownload()
Dim IExpl As Object
Set IExpl = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IExpl
.Navigate "http://www.bom.mu/?id=80277" 'You need to change this for a variable and loop
Do Until .Readystate = 4: Loop ' Allow page to load
'Code below to find correct href link in page based on text
For Each lnk In IExpl.Application.Document.Links
If lnk.outertext = "Click Here to Open or Right Click to Download." Then Exit For
Debug.Print lnk.outertext
Next
End With
SuccessfulDownload = URLDownloadToFileA(0, lnk.href, "C:\myfilename.zip", 0, 0)
Set IExpl = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @ryguy.  How is it different from what I posted?  The command that initiates the download:  ret = URLDownloadToFile... is identical.  What of your code will keep the download from terminating prematurely?

Comment: Look at the If ret = 0 Then part.  You can handle the timeout that way.  Beyond re-trying the download process, I don't know how to guarantee that it downloads the file.  It must be a pretty massive file!

Comment: It seems that the 'If ret = 0 then' part runs after the file has been interrupted.  The file is about 1 GB, but not the fastest connection.  Thanks for the help Ryguy.

Comment: AFAIK, the readystate is only for the web browser, and it has nothing at all to do with the process of downloading files.

Comment: Do you use VB.NET?  You could try this.  http://www.aeronav.faa.gov/upload_313-/terminal/DDTPPE_201612.zip

Answer (score 0):

Or, try R, which is blazing fast!! In order to get your data to download and uncompress, you need to set `mode="wb"`

```
download.file("...",temp, mode="wb") 
unzip(temp, "gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv") 
dd <- read.table("gbr_Country_en_csv_v2.csv", sep=",",skip=2, header=T)
```

Then, simply read the CSV from your Excel tool.